# Raising exceptions with django_rest_framework

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, exception, django-rest-framework

I have written a view that decrypts a GPG encrypted file and returns it as plain text. This works fine in general. The problem is, if the file is empty or otherwise contains invalid GPG data, gnupg returns an empty result rather than throw an exception.

I need to be able to do something like this inside *decrypt_file* to check to see if the decryption failed and raise an error:

```
if data.ok:
    return str(data)
else:
    raise APIException(data.status)
```

If I do this, I see the APIException raised in the Django debug output, but it's not translating to a 500 response to the client. Instead the client gets a 200 response with an empty body. I can raise the APIException in my *get* method and it sends a 500 response, but there I don't have access to the gnupg error message.

Here is a very simplified version of my view:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.core import files
from gnupg import GPG

class FileDownload(APIView):
    def decrypt_file(self, file):
        gpg = GPG()
        data = gpg.decrypt(file.read())
        return data

    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        f = open('/tmp/foo', 'rb')
        file = files.File(f)
        return FileResponse(self.decrypt_file(file))
```

I have read the docs on DRF exception handling [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/), but it doesn't seem to provide a solution to this problem. I am fairly new to Django and python in general, so it's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious. Helpful advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you raise an error in python, every function in the trace re-raise it until someone catch it. You can first declare a exception :

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class ServiceUnavailable(APIException):
    status_code = 503
    default_detail = 'Service temporarily unavailable, try again later.'
```

Then in your `decrypt_file` function, raise this exception if decryption is not successful. You can pass an argument to modify the message. Then, in the `get` method, you should call `decrypt_file` function and pass your file as an argument. If any things goes wrong, your function raise that exception and then, get method re-raise it until Django Rest Framework exception handler catch it.
**EDIT:** 
In your decrypt function, do something like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

def decrypt_file(self, file):
    ... # your codes
    if data.ok:
        return str(data)
    else:
        raise ServiceUnavailable

def get(self, request, id, format=None):
    f = open('/tmp/foo', 'rb')
    result = decrypt_file(f)
    f.close()
    return Response({'data': result})
```

Comment: When I try that and hit it with curl I get:

    curl: (52) Empty reply from server

The django log shows:
    [30/Dec/2015 21:10:47] "GET /files/56833fe5e138236d46b1385c HTTP/1.1" 500 59

So, it's returning a 500, but not a JSON body with the error message.

Comment: Actually, it;s throwing a 500, not the 503 set in the exception class. In the log I see "ServiceUnavailable: Service temporarily unavailable, try again later.", so that goes off, but the 500 is due to "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'" which happens because the ServiceUnavailable exception is not fatal and the function passes a blank result back to the calling function, which expects some data.

Comment: I've just edited the answer. Check it out and tell me if the problem exists.